# Cheese not working properly

Tags: webcam, cheese

Ubuntu 22.04
Cheese 41.1
Logitech webcam

Taking a picture with Cheese it starts counting 3 2 1 then shows an error “There was an error playing video from webcam”.
Change the resolution up and down with the same result.
I always had Cheese working properly with previous Ubuntu versions.
Tried to start in Terminal gave these errors:

```
luis@l-System-luisj:~$ cheese
```

Cheese started click “Take Photo” counting 3 2 1 come a black screen with error above mentioned and these warning in Terminal.

```
(cheese:16986): cheese-WARNING **: 10:15:07.097: Output state was not configured: ../gst-libs/gst/video/gstvideoencoder.c(2281): gst_video_encoder_can_push_unlocked (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstEncodeBin:image-encodebin/GstJpegEnc:jpegenc0
```

Quit Cheese these error come up

```
(cheese:16986): Clutter-CRITICAL **: 10:15:32.762: Unable to create dummy onscreen: No foreign surface, and wl_shell unsupported by the compositor
luis@l-System-luisj:~$
```

Can some one help to correct this?
Thank you